# Create a paused trigger

Tags: c#, quartz.net

Is it possible to add a trigger to the scheduler in a paused state? I've found that if I don't specify a start time it will start immediately.

Other than immediately calling `scheduler.PauseJob` can this be done another way?

```
var trigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
    .ForJob(job)
    .WithSimpleSchedule(schedule => schedule.WithIntervalInMinutes(1).RepeatForever())
    .Build();

scheduler.ScheduleJob(job, trigger);

// Pause job immediately
scheduler.PauseJob(job.Key);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've checked the repository and it does not seem to be possible.
You cannot pause a trigger/job until it has been scheduled.

`Scheduler.PauseTrigger` and `Scheduler.PauseJob` set the state of the trigger to `InternalTriggerState.Paused` ([see reference](https://github.com/quartznet/quartznet/blob/master/src/Quartz/Simpl/RAMJobStore.cs#L1961))

I would suggest you to schedule your trigger delaying the start a little bit and pause it immediately.

```
var trigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
    .ForJob(job)
    .WithSimpleSchedule(schedule => schedule.WithIntervalInMinutes(1).RepeatForever())
    .StartAt(SystemTime.UtcNow().AddSeconds(5))
    .Build();

scheduler.ScheduleJob(job, trigger);

scheduler.PauseTrigger(trigger.Key);
```

Comment: It actually is possible with trigger groups -- check my answer.

Comment: @nollidge: Thanks for the clarification. This answer is 4 years old, though.

Answer (score 4):

It is actually possible to do this with trigger groups. You just need to pause a particular trigger group, and then create a job whose trigger(s) belong to that group.

```
// pauses the group, if it isn't already
scheduler.PauseTriggers(GroupMatcher<TriggerKey>.GroupEquals("PausedGroup"));

var job = JobBuilder.Create<MyJob>().WithIdentity(jobName).Build();

var trigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
    .ForJob(job)
    .WithIdentity(Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), "PausedGroup")
    .WithSimpleSchedule(schedule => schedule.WithIntervalInMinutes(1).RepeatForever())
    .Build();

scheduler.ScheduleJob(job, trigger);
```

Then to resume the job, reschedule each trigger with a different group:

```
foreach (var oldTrigger in scheduler.GetTriggers(new JobKey(jobName)))
{
    // clone the old trigger with new group name
    var newTrigger = oldTrigger.GetTriggerBuilder()
        .WithIdentity(oldTrigger.Key.Name) // uses default trigger group name
        .Build();

    // not a typo, the method to reschedule a trigger is called "RescheduleJob" for some reason
    scheduler.RescheduleJob(oldTrigger.Key, newTrigger);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution is to use the StartAt() method on the trigger builder to set a specific start time.

e.g. to delay start for 30mins:

```
var trigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
    .ForJob(job)
    .WithSimpleSchedule(schedule => schedule.WithIntervalInMinutes(1).RepeatForever())
    .StartAt(DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(30))
    .Build();
```